# Accessing a dynamic vector of vector

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;

v.push_back(std::vector<int>(2));
v[0].push_back(10);

std::cout<<(v[0])[0];
```

But it prints "0" instead of 10.

I am trying to make a dynamic vector that holds a vector with fixed size.

Can someone help me visualize what's happening?

Comment: Hint: read up on what `push_back` does.

Answer (score 3):

The code is buggy:

```
std::vector<int>(2)
```

makes a vector of size 2 initialized with deault constructed `int` (which is zero), so pushing `10` just makes a vector of size 3 w/ `10` at the end (index 2).

Comment: but i used `v[0].push_back(10);`    if i will initialize the main vector with fixed size `std::vector< std::vector<int> > v(2);` then it will print 10.

Comment: @CarloBrew, initially your "main" vector is empty, then you add a vector of size 2 to it (at index 0). after that you append `10` to the just added vector, so latter become size 3 (with `10` at index 2): `assert(v[0].size() == 3u && v[0][2] == 10)`. But your "main" vector still have size 1.

Comment: @CarloBrew: Vectors never have a fixed size, so no. What you're _actually_ doing is creating a vector with an initial size, then adding an extra element to the end.

Comment: I have come up with another solution: `std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
 v.resize(2, std::vector<int>(2,2));`   is this acceptable? I plan on using resize if i will increase the size.

Comment: Being pedantic about terminology: the int is *value-initialized* which yields `0`.  A default-initialized int would be uninitialized. Primitives types don't have constructors, there are just the initialization rules. vector's default allocator uses value-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about push_back, here's what i understand so far and how i fixed it

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vo;    //empty vector of vectors
v.push_back(std::vector<int>(2));      //insert element
v.push_back(std::vector<int>(2));      //insert element

v[0][0] = 1;                           
v[0][1] = 2;                           //allocated so it's alright to add elements
v[1][0] = 3;
v[1][1] = 4;
std::cout<<v[1][1]; //4
```

Comment: Note that the inner vectors can still be resized. Making std::vector non-resizable is not a trivial task, and if required for an assignment, your instructor is a right bastard.

Comment: you mean v[0].resize?

Comment: clear, insert, erase, push_back, pop_back, resize, emplace and emplace_back will all change the size of both the inner and outer vectors.